# How to get the refresh token from Firebase.auth.currentUser Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, jwt, refresh-token

I am breaking my head on how to get the refresh token from `FirebaseAuth` but cannot seem to find how.

On iOS, the equivalent is `Auth.auth().currentUser?.refreshToken`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, did you found the answer? I'm in the same position right now

Comment: me2, I keep fetching the wrong data because of that..

Comment: I think it’s just not possible. Firebase does not allow access to refresh token on Android. Maybe this is due to security reason where on iOS you can store it in KeyChaim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what Furkan meant to say:

Use the forceRefresh parameter. This force refreshes the token. Should only be set to true if the token is invalidated

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.getIdToken(true)
```

Read this answer for when you should use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48599373/1772057

Answer (score 1):

Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427901/6534576

Maybe you solution is use the getIdToken listener.

- getIdToken(true) only if you want refresh the token
- getIdToken(false) if you only want get the current

code

```
user.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener { result ->
      val token = result.token
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firebaseUser. getIdToken()  reloads your token

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.